# Loading detail from database with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying something very simple yet can't make it work and I have no idea why. I'm trying to load details on bootstrap modal windows from database so I can edit them. My button looks like

```
<button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['row_id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
```

Then this is the php part which should load the data

```
include("../../misc/database.inc.php");


error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['row_id']) && isset($_POST['row_id']) != "") {

    $row_id = $_POST['row_id'];                 
    $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT row_id, row_content, row_email FROM excel_table WHERE row_id =  ?'); 
    $value->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->execute();

    $response = array();

    if($value->rowCount() > 0){
         while ($rs = $value->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             $response = $row;

         }                  
    }
    else
    {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = "Data not found!";
    }   
    echo json_encode($response);
    //var_dump($_POST['row_id']); // return correct id
}
```

On the console->Network I see correct response

> {"row_id":"1","row_content":"asd","row_email":"sad"}

Here is js part which should load data

```
function GetUserDetails(row_id) {

    $("#row_id").val(row_id);
    $.post("ajax/readUserDetails.php", {
            row_id: row_id
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // PARSE json data
            var excel_table = JSON.parse(data);
            // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
            $("#row_content").val(excel_table.row_content);
            $("#row_email").val(excel_table.row_email);
        }
    );
    // Open modal popup
    $("#update_user_modal").modal("show");
}
```

And this is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_user_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="row_content">Desc</label>
                    <input type="text" id="row_content" placeholder="Описание" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="row_email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="row_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="row_id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why modal isn't populated with data?

Comment: Yes, on button submit `row_id:1` and response `{"row_id":"1","row_content":"asd","row_email":"sad"}`

Comment: did you debug your code?

Comment: I've tried what I know. So far to see what I sent and receive on button click. What else I can debug?

Comment: I mean do you know where is the problem? We cant debug the code for you.  you ask `why modal isn't populated with data?`, then you check where you populate your data.

Comment: I believe the problem is in js part because the query is fine and no errors. Meaning next step is to be parsed from js to modal.

Comment: you know debug js? you mean after this `$("#row_content").val(excel_table.row_content);` the row_content isnt update?

Comment: Yes, modal is empty when I open it. No, I'm not really familiar how to debug js.

Comment: Is ok. I want suggest you check first two videos from [**HERE**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=debug+js)

Answer (score 2):

well my guess is you need to show the modal after the ajax asynchronous call end.

```
function GetUserDetails(row_id) {

    $("#row_id").val(row_id);
    $.post("ajax/readUserDetails.php", {
            row_id: row_id
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // PARSE json data
            var excel_table = JSON.parse(data);
            // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields

            //add console.log to make sure you have some value
            console.log('row_content: ' + excel_table.row_content);

            $("#row_content").val(excel_table.row_content);
            $("#row_email").val(excel_table.row_email);

            // then add another to make sure you update it correctly.
            console.log('#row_content: ' + $("#row_content").val());

           // Open modal popup AFTER YOU UPDATE 
           $("#update_user_modal").modal("show");
        }
    );     
}
```

Comment: Same result. Array response in console is correct `{row_id: "1", row_content: "asd", row_email: "sad"}` but modal is empty

Comment: I didn't mention it but I using this tutorial and I've changing it a bit because I want to implement pdo... etc: http://www.itechempires.com/2016/03/php-mysql-crud-create-read-update-delete-operations-using-jquery/

Comment: Try with the console.log to see what is happening. But you should check the videos to learn how debug.

Comment: I've got this `row_content: asd  #row_content: asd`

Comment: Ok, Im out ideas. If `#row_content: asd` your modal shouldnt be empty

Comment: I know must be populated.. That's why I posted the question in case I miss something.